# Program won't check if its a valid triangle

Tags: python, python-3.x

Early stuff for my midterm, supposed to take user input, check if all three inputs are above 0, then have program to check for what triangle it is. I have everything working except the program won't give me the "Invalid triangle" print when it is true, instead it gives "This is another triangle!". Help please.

```
def checktriangle():
    active = True
    while active:
        A = int(input("Please enter the 1st side length: "))
        if A <= 0: # checks if negative or less than 0, if so asks again
            int(input("Please enter a number bigger not negative or 0: "))

        B = int(input("Please enter the 2nd side length: "))
        if B <= 0: # checks if negative or less than 0, if so asks again
            int(input("Please enter a number bigger not negative or 0: "))

        C = int(input("Please enter the 3rd side length: "))
        if C <= 0: # checks if negative or less than 0, if so asks again
            int(input("Please enter a number bigger not negative or 0: "))

        if (A * A) + (B * B) == C * C or (A * A) + (C * C) == C * C or (C * C) + (B * B) == A * A:
            print ("Right triangle")
            prompt = input ("Would you like restart?: ")
            if prompt.lower() == 'y':
                continue
            elif prompt.lower()== 'n':
                active = False
                break

        elif A == B == C:
            print ("Equilateral triangle")
            prompt = input ("Would you like restart?: ")
            if prompt.lower() == 'y':
                continue
            elif prompt.lower() == 'n':
                active = False
                break

        elif A == B or A == C or B == C:
            print ("Isosceles triangle")
            prompt = input ("Would you like restart?: ")
            if prompt.lower() == 'y':
                continue
            elif prompt.lower() == 'n':
                active = False
                break

        elif A!= B or A != C or B != C or (A * A) + (B * B) != C * C or (A * A) + (C * C) != C * C or (C * C) + (B * B) != A * A or A != B != C:
            print ("This is another triangle!")
            prompt = input ("Would you like restart?: ")
            if prompt.lower() == 'y':
                continue
            elif prompt.lower() == 'n':
                active = False
                break

        elif A + B < C or A + C < B or B + C < A:
            print ("Invalid triangle")
            prompt = input ("Would you like restart?: ")
            if prompt.lower() == 'y':
                continue
            elif prompt.lower() == 'n':
                active = False
                break

checktriangle()
```

Comment: You didn't left much chance for the last `elif`... As long as 2 sides are different it will immediately become `another triangle` because the use of `or`

Comment: Also, just a side note, note how the `would you like to restart` part is reapeating many times? It might better to just put it once **after all** conditions no? And you actually don't need the `active` variable as you're `break`ing anyway

Comment: `(A * A) + (C * C) == C * C` has little chance of happening...